# Reveal website content under image in a "scratch card way"

Tags: javascript, mouseover, interactive

I'm not sure what to call this considering and I come here for help.
More than looking for a solution to my problem, I'm looking for resources to something I don't know what it's called.

I've had the idea of reproduce [this](https://codepen.io/InsideDown/pen/rjPEdM) but with my entire website content under the image and in a permanent matter.
I figured it's something related with Canvas and JavaScript but I'm not sure what to call it. It's not mouse trail but it's related with the coordinates of the cursor.
I figured I could do something similar to this codepen and have the images disappear at a certain point to reveal the website but that doesn't seem ideal and/or responsive.

And that's about what I know about this specific issue.
Even if I want to do it's not possible, if you could direct me in the right direction to get some documentation about this, I would really appreciate it.

The code pasted underneath is just so the question could be approved. I think that the link to the codepen displays entirely what I mean.

```
    //this is a sample flashlight effect

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#light").css({
      "top": e.pageY - 250,
      "left": e.pageX - 250
    })
  }).mousedown(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 1:
            $("#light").toggleClass("light-off");
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Nothing like this is built into javascript. At the bare minimum you will need to learn how to detect hover events and use them to make changes to your page with javascript. You will also need to learn css to understand how to enhance the graphics, or you could use something like html canvas perhaps. Or you could find a library that does all of this for you, but don't know of any (nor is stackoverflow the place to ask for library recommendations). Try googling "reveal website contents on mouseover" or "show content on hover javascript".

Comment: This might be more what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/Totati/pen/pPXrJV/?editors=0110